# required node/express modules not updating with chokidar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I've read a number of questions and answers on here regarding chokidar, however I'm still stumped... so would really appreciate anyone that can debug my specific snippet.

I'm running a basic Express node app at localhost:3000.

Entry point is app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const clearRequire = require('clear-require');

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const app = express();

// config nunjucks
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    watch: true,
    nocache: true,
    express: app
});

// Routes for Express into modules
var index = require('./routes/index');
var game  = require('./routes/game');

if (!production) {
    const chokidar = require('chokidar');
    const watcher = chokidar.watch('./routes');

    watcher
        .on('ready', () => console.log('Scan complete. Ready for changes.'))
        .on('change', path => {
            var clearPath = "./" + path.split(".")[0];
            clearRequire(clearPath);
        });
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'njk');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/game', game);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', { test: 'test'});
  next();
});

module.exports = app;
```

and within ./routes/game.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET game page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('game', { title: 'Game', also: 'test-4' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Updating game.js (e.g., change "test-4" to "test-5") has no effect to the app without restarting the server. I had presumed that chokidar would allow me to update game.js and have the changes reflect on next page load?

For reference the game.njk template looks like this:

```
{% extends "app.njk" %}

{% block pageContent %}
    <div id="pageContent" class="container">
        This. is. game. {{ also }}
    </div><!-- /#pageContent .container -->
{% endblock pageContent %}
```

If I update the template, it updates instantly (as per nunjucks watch: true statement) but no luck on the also var updating.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're clearing the cache, you're not renewing the `game` route. The cache flushing will work for newly required modules, but won't have any effect for already required ones. So you need to require again the game route after clearing the cache.

```
watcher
        .on('ready', () => console.log('Scan complete. Ready for changes.'))
        .on('change', path => {
            var clearPath = "./" + path.split(".")[0];
            clearRequire(clearPath);

            //Move this code elsewhere or not...
            if(path == "routes/game.js"){
               //renew game route
               game = require("./routes/game");
            }
        });
```

And then change:

```
app.use('/game', game); //Changing game won't have any effect
```

To:

```
app.use('/game', function(req, res, next){
    game(req, res, next); //This game will have the renewed route
});
```

---

In any case I would recommend using [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/)

> Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development. Install it using npm.
>
> Just use nodemon instead of node to run your code, and now your
>   process will automatically restart when your code changes. To install,
>   get node.js, then from your terminal run:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And then:

```
nodemon server.js
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for this. I had already started trying to use nodemon instead of chokidar, however that wasn't running the server correctly when I started it until I realised that express has the app start from bin/www (which your post prompted me to explore and finally determine)

Comment: Glad it helped, have fun with nodemon! it really is the way to go!